# Flurry SDK for Android using AIR 3.0

Tags: android, flash, air, adobe, flurry

I am writing application for Android using Adobe AIR 3.0. And I need to integrate Flurry analytics in this project. On official site http://www.flurry.com/   I downloaded Flurry SDK for Android. It is jar file. How can I integrate it to my action script 3 project? I am using Flash builder 4.6. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Develop a native extension.

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/developing-native-extensions-air.html

Answer (score 1):

You cannot as far as I can tell.  There is no way to include native development SDKs in your Air/Flex applications.

The problem is that your AIR application doesn't have direct access to the native SDKs functionality; only the functionality that Adobe has bubbled to the surface.  Since Flurry's SDK interacts directly with the native Java implementation, Adobe would have to write code to let those events, triggers, methods & classes be accessible inside of the AIR runtime.